# How to use modman in windows for xampp server

Tags: development, windows, modman

I want to use modman in localhost in xampp for windows.

How can I achieve this? Is there any example for usage of modman for custom modules as well as 3rd party modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modman does not work on Windows. For Windows you can use the [modman-php](https://github.com/sitewards/modman-php) port, it's not super stable on all platforms, but it works on Windows.

But you have to run it with permissions to create symlinks. You need to open the command prompt with "run as administrator", or change the policy for your user as described in https://superuser.com/questions/104845/permission-to-make-symbolic-links-in-windows-7 (only works for users that are not in the administrator group)

Answer (score 0):

> **For Magento Users**
>
> If using template files in a modman module, you must either:
>
> **Option 1:**
>
> Use a patched version of `Mage/Core/Block/Template.php`. This gist is
>   itself a modman module so you can install it by cloning it directly or
>   you can integrate it into your environment some other way.
>
> $ modman clone template-patch
>   https://gist.github.com/35c0d32dd651c4c8c840.git NOTE: I provide no
>   warranties for using this patch. Use at your own risk!
>
> **Option 2:**
>
> Enable "Allow Symlinks" (found under `System > Configuration >
>   Advanced > Developer`).
>
> ```
> Allow Symlinks
> ```
>
> NOTE: Disabling this security protection does decrease security as it
>   allows template files to be loaded from any location. However, the
>   risk is not so much symlinks as it is specially crafted template
>   paths. The patched Template.php file (Option 1) allows the use of
>   symlinks but should still prevent templates from being loaded from
>   directories other than the app/design directory.
>
> **Windows Users**
>
> Windows (including cygwin) is not supported by this script, but there
>   is a PHP-port of modman which works on Windows. [Link](https://github.com/sitewards/modman-php)
>
> **Installation**
>
> To install Modman, you can either install the library in your user's
>   root folder, or you can install Modman globally. Regardless of which
>   option you choose, first run one of these two scripts to download the
>   Modman repo.
>
> ```
> bash < <(wget -q --no-check-certificate -O - https://raw.github.com/colinmollenhour/modman/master/modman-installer)
>
> or
>
> bash < <(curl -s -L https://raw.github.com/colinmollenhour/modman/master/modman-installer)
> ```
>
> 1. Root Folder
>
> If you'd like to keep the script in its native location at `~/bin/`,
>   just reload your Bash profile.
>
> source ~/.profile
>   2. Installing Modman Globally
>
> To make the script global after downloading, move the Modman script to
>   an appropriate script folder, (e.g. /usr/local/bin/ or something
>   similar within `/usr/*`). Moving it to one of the paths already loaded
>   in your $PATH variable will automatically pick it up without a
>   ~/.profile reload.
>
> ```
> mv ~/bin/modman /usr/local/{{ preferred folder }}
> ```
>
> And then finally, alias Modman with a symlink if you want something
>   shorter to type (optional)
>
> ```
> ln -s /usr/local/{{ preferred folder }}/modman /usr/local/{{ preferred folder }}/{{ symlink }}
> ```
>
> Note: modman is simply a bash script, so to use it you just need to
>   place it in your $PATH and change its mode to executable.

[Source](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/modman)

Comment: for install where to run above script in windows?

Comment: I take long time to make grip on modman.anyways thanks